# Django read after update is not getting the latest value

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, mariadb

I am working on a Django project that uses MariaDB as the database. The project has a state serialized to the database and it is updated frequently via REST API posting. I use a serializer to handle the state update by calling `update(instance, validated_data)`. Then I send a WebSocket message to the browser client using Django Channels.

The browser client listens for the WebSocket message and requests the latest state using `get`.

I run Django with Uvicorn and 6 worker threads in production.

However, I encounter a problem where the client sometimes gets an old state, the state prior to the last update. This causes the client to display incorrect information.

I suspect this is related to the database isolation level being `READ COMMITTED`. Would changing it to `SERIALIZABLE` solve the issue? Or can I set different isolation levels for specific tables that need more strict locking?

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you committing your database update before sending the WebSocket message?

Comment: what I'm hearing is the client is getting state using get, independent of whatever updates are happening, and that get is sometimes getting a state that doesn't include updates that should have completed?  that makes no sense unless you have some caching layer or are not commiting your updates.  if the situation where the bug is happening is more complex, please clarify.

Comment: @BillKarwin I am not using transaction because the update and get are different requests. Would transaction help?

Comment: @ysth Yes the client is getting the state using get, which is independent of the post. I am not using transaction or atomic. I do have a caching layer. 
T0: External entity submitted a post to update the state
T1: Django handling POST: update database, emit a websocket message to client.
T2: Client received websocket message, submitted a get request to get the latest state
T3: Django handling GET: query the database, sending it back to client with an old state

Comment: If you aren't using a transaction, sure sounds like you are sending the websocket message before the database update, and you need to figure out why.

Comment: @ysth Thanks for the pointers. Since my update is only one statement, I didn't think transaction is necessary. But I think I can use transaction.on_commit to make sure I am sending the websocket message after the update is committed.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit

Comment: Also, I am adding `never_cache` to my views. This should stop the browser from caching my result, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BillKarwin and @ysth suggested, it does sound like I am sending websocket message before database update is committed. I think I can use `transaction.on_commit` to make sure it does not happen.

Also, I have added `never_cached` to my views. This should stop browsers caching my results.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit